# Convert WPF to NetCore 3: The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.DesktopUI' was not recognized

Tags: wpf, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to convert my existing **wpf** project to .net core 3.
I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_4-dH-JY-M) , and i get this erreur after  reloading the project:

```
The FrameworkReference 'Microsoft.DesktopUI' was not recognized
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: Is it this problem? https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk/issues/134

Comment: Did you try to install Visual Studio 2019 and create a new WPF .NET Core project? If you do this, you should be able to simply move your existing source files to the new project more or less.

Comment: I use visual studio 2019 Community, as the previous versions of VS ,there is a template for WPF (.net Framework)